# Life Cycle of Java Application

Tags: java, lifecycle

Its most known question Applet vs Application and common answer is applet starts from `init()` whereas application starts from `main()`.

**Life cycle of Applet : init() -> start() -> paint() -> stop() -> destroy()**

but, what about, application ?? it starts from **main()** then **destroy()** ?? or it depends on coding part ?? Please correct me, if i'm wrong at any point.

Let say this is the simple java code

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String  args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World !!");
    }
}
```

I found [this](http://technofriends.in/2007/09/30/java-lifecycle-of-a-java-program/), but i think, this is the common life cycle to all (applet, servlet, application).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you posted talks about the cycle of creating an application.

For a Java Application the lifecycle is only the `main()` function. The application will end when all non-demon threads have terminated (threads are non-demon by default) or when `System.exit()` is called.

If you don't start any threads, the only thread is the main thread, which will terminate at the end of the `main()` function.

Comment: Additionally: If you create, for example a swing application, there will be an AWT-Event-Thread created. This thread keeps the application alive until you destroy the last (J)Frame [or (J)Window?].

Comment: Indeed many libraries will create non-demon threads, each library will have to explain you how to exit gracefully. In the case of Swing you need to call system.exit() or (have the framework call it when a certain frame/window closes) it will not exit automatically.

Comment: and what, if i included `MyClass m = new MyClass()`. There isn't anything like object allocation or something like ??

Comment: the created instance of `MyClass` stored in the variable `m` would be garbage collected because you dont use it. And there is still no thread after finishing `main()`

Comment: @Thirler which means in the life cycle of java application, it start from main() and then destroy() ?? there isn't anything in between main() and destroy()??

Comment: `destroy()` doesn't exist for an application. After `main()` finishes there is only the non-demon threads keeping the application alive.

Comment: @Thirler you mean it has only one method that starts from main and end with main. isn't??

Comment: Main is called only once. When it is done, your application is done. There is no function called at the end of the application (although you can register shutdown hooks that will be called at the exit)

Answer (score 0):

Want to add on top of @Thirler post.

Life time of classes **which don't have main** method are controlled by the scope of their objects. So once any objects gets created ( by new ) they come into existence and they go out of scope when the number of references created for the class becomes 0.

So life time of a class ends once all objects are garbage collected and also if their are no weak,soft and phantom references.

Life Cycle:

**Class Load --> Object Creation--> All objects nullified  --> garbage collection ---> End**

Comment: so what exactly is the life cycle, can you sequence them??

Comment: then, where is main method called ??

Comment: This is for classed which don't have main.

Comment: which means.. you are talking about the general form (including applet, servlet,jsp and all) of java code. isn't ??

Comment: right..this is normally the case in a java/j2ee project where you might just have one entry point through main.